# Prove the convergence of the sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove the convergence of the following sequence:
$$x_1 = \sqrt{a}$$

$$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{a + x_n}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share your approach? It helps the MSE provide better feedback. Regards

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** :

Prove that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and monotonic

Comment: You're using a proved theorem, but how can I prove that the sequence is bounded ?

Comment: Can you prove by induction that $x_n<a+1,\forall n\in \mathbb N$? Then the sequence will be incresasing and bounded above, therefore convergent.

Answer (score 1):

(Of couse we need $a\ge 0$ as premise)

1. Show by induction that $0\le x_n<a+1$
2. Show by induction that $x_{n+1}\ge x_n$

(You can facilitate things a bit by prepending a term $x_0=0$. Not that then still $x_1=\sqrt{a+x_0}$)